# If/While (second not working)

Tags: php, wordpress

Can somebody explain to me what the difference is between:

`<? php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

and

`<? php if (have_posts()) { while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); } } ?>`

Comment: Both shouldn't work! You can't have a space here: `<? php` should be `<?php`

Comment: The syntax of the first one seems wrong to me. The colon is reserved for the "else" branch of the ternary operator. Not to mention the fact that `if(condition) ... while(condition)` is redundant.

Comment: It's not being used as a ternary operator...

Comment: the first one is missing `endif/endwhile`. @BrianDriscoll: it's not a ternary. it's php's [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which wordpress is married to.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the clarification, I can't say that I have much exposure to the alternative syntax which is probably why I didn't recognize it as such.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: it's best to avoid it. wordpuke (not a typo) is at the best of times horrible to deal with. the alternative syntax just makes it that much more fun.

Comment: I find the alternative syntax to be easier to read...at least when it comes to the WordPress Loop, and outputting `the_content()`. But not everyone agrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the fact that you can't have a space between the `<? php`...They're both the same.

The first is what's referred to as [the alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

The full statements should look something like:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Your post html -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

And...

```
<?php if (have_posts()) { 
          while ( have_posts() ) { 
              the_post(); ?>

     <!-- Your post html -->

<?php } } ?>
```